# browser.executeScript doesn't see $scope

Tags: angularjs, protractor

i am making a test with protractor for my angularjs app
and i came accross the following problem

what i want to do is :

```
browser.executeScript('$scope.$apply')
```

i want to do this so that my screen updates/renders so i can get the values on screen

only when i do this it says : $scope is not defined

if have also tried multiple javascript render ways who also failed ,but i am not sure if i have used the right methods for that...

does anybody has the same problem or know how to fix this?

Comment: What does your test look like? Does it have `$scope`?

Comment: `$scope` is not a global variable. 

But i don't understand what you are trying to do with protractor. Protractor is an e2e testing tool. That means that you interact with **user interface** an check the result on the **user interface**. May you should write some unit tests instead.

Comment: I was trying to check some variable values at certain points in the test

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should be using an ng-view directive in your container markup to render html snippets or partials within your index page. Take a look at what ng-view can do (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive:ngView) :-)